# wget --accept files containing pattern

Tags: string, wget

I am trying to write a script that downloads all the files linked in a certain page. These files must contain specific strings and have certain extensions.
Let's say that I want to download all files that contain the string "1080" or "1080p" etc. and that have as extension ".mov" ".avi" ".wmv" etc. This was to show that both the strings and the extensions are multiple.

This is what I have done so far:

```
wget -Amov -r -np -nc -l1 --no-check-certificate -e robots=off http://www.example.com
```

Any help is really apreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a pattern for the -A switch, like this:

```
wget -A "*1080*mov" -r -np -nc -l1 --no-check-certificate -e robots=off http://www.example.com
```

This example will get all files with "1080", except gif & png files:

```
wget -A "*1080*" -R gif,png -r -np -nc -l1 --no-check-certificate -e robots=off http://www.example.com
```